# PR2_controller Plugin Nothing happened in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I followed the tutorial [pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Running a real-time Cartesian/controller](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Running%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller) exactly to write a pr2 controller. Everything seems fine except nothing happened in the gazebo simulator. Could anyone help me out? I describe what I have done as follows:

**package name: my_controller_cart_pkg**

**Plugin class defined:**

```
namespace my_controller_ns{
class MyCartControllerClass: public pr2_controller_interface::Controller
{....
}
```

**Plugin declaration in src/my_controller_cart.cpp:**

```
PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS (my_controller_cart_pkg, MyCartControllerClass,
                         my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass,
                         pr2_controller_interface::Controller)
```

Actually, I also tried PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS(MyCartControllerClass,
my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass,
pr2_controller_interface::Controller), but it didn't work.

**controller_plugins.xml:**

```
<library path="lib/libmy_controllers">
  <class name="my_controller_cart_pkg/MyCartControllerClass" 
         type="my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass"           
         base_class_type="pr2_controller_interface::Controller" />
</library>
```

**cart_controller.yaml:**

```
my_tutorial_controller:
    type: my_controller_cart_pkg/MyCartControllerClass
    root_name: torso_lift_link
    tip_name: r_gripper_tool_frame
```

**my_controller_cart.launch:**

```
<launch>
   <rosparam file="$(find my_controller_cart_pkg)/cart_controller.yaml" command="load" />

   <node pkg="pr2_controller_manager" type="spawner" args="my_tutorial_controller" name="my_controller_cart_spawner" />
</launch>
```

After I launched the gazebo simulator, I typed:

> rosrun pr2_controller_manager
> pr2_controller_manager list-types

Then I can see:

> JointGravityController
>
> JointPendulumController
>
> ethercat_trigger_controllers/MultiTriggerController
>
> ethercat_trigger_controllers/ProjectorController
>
> ethercat_trigger_controllers/TriggerController
>
> **my_controller_cart_pkg/MyCartControllerClass**
>
> ...

After that, I launched my **my_controller_cart.launch** file. I run:

> rosrun pr2_controller_manager
> pr2_controller_manager list

I received:

> base_controller ( running )
>
> base_odometry ( running )
>
> head_traj_controller ( running )
>
> l_arm_controller ( running )
>
> l_gripper_controller ( running )
>
> laser_tilt_controller ( running )
>
> **my_tutorial_controller ( running )**
>
> r_arm_controller ( running )
>
> r_gripper_controller ( running )
>
> torso_controller ( running )

my_tutorial_controller plugin is running. But nothing happened in gazebo simulator.
Could anyone help me out? Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49787/pr2_controller-plugin-nothing-happened-in-gazebo/) by [Xiaolong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3725/xiaolong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xiaolong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3725/xiaolong/) on 2012-12-06**:
I noticed a similar question posted previously, but it didn't solve my problem. http://answers.ros.org/question/45279/pr2-writing-a-realtime-joint-controller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I happened to change the cart_controller.yaml file to control the left arm. It works!

```
my_tutorial_controller:
    type: my_controller_cart_pkg/MyCartControllerClass
    root_name: torso_lift_link
    tip_name: l_gripper_tool_frame
```

Now I want to know why the right arm doesn't work?

---

Originally posted by [Xiaolong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3725/xiaolong/) with karma: 66 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on 2012-12-06**:
Wow, yes it works on the left arm too for the tutorial that I was stuck on.

**Comment by [Xiaolong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3725/xiaolong/) on 2012-12-07**:
Did you figure out why it doesn't work on the right arm?

**Comment by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on 2013-02-22**:
I found that if I kill the right_arm_controller, it and load my_controller_name afterwards, the right arm works. @.@ perhaps the default controller was interfering?